# How can I synchronize local database to cpanel database

Tags: xampp, cpanel, data-synchronization

i am creating a laravel application and want to host windows PC with data synchronization on my live host cpanel. It is possible or not? if yes, how can i do synchronization my local Xampp project phpmyadmin database in my cpanel phpmyadmin database. Xampp is compatible for large amount of data or not?

Give the local database to live database synchronization idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your database from your xampp control panel and import it in your phpmyadmin of cpanel